# Why ngCordova geolocation watch isn't working?

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I want to make an hybrid app that shows me live my location. I'm using ionic and ngCordova geolocation plugin.To see if my location is changed,they have a function with $watch that can detect if location has been changed. I've run their code.It takes my location ,but it can't watch.Does anybody knows something about this?